# How to check whether session presents or not in android?

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android and I built a app that uses sessions.

I use `DefaultHttpClient` and it maintains session for me by default.

But before I can do a `GET` for example:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("someurl.com");
httpClient.execute(httpget);
```

Before this step can I do a check on if whether the session exists for that current request?

Are there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The HTTP session is maintained by a cookie. The client needs to ensure that it properly sends the cookie back on the subsequent requests as per the HTTP spec.